# split current url after "=" character with php

Tags: php, url, split

i need help with this code.

need get only last part of the current url with php.

example: `http://www.site.com/index.php?user=username bla bla and the rest words`

get all url after **=** character, i need only **username bla bla and the rest words**

for javascript: `document.URL.split("=")[1];`

i need for php please, thanks.

i have tried with this code but not works,

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: There's also no need for splitting it out, as using `$_GET` seems apt for the current url/page.

Answer (score 4):

```
$current_url =  $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; 
$a=explode("=",$current_url);
    echo $a[1];
```

//OR for CI framework

```
$current_url =  current_url();
$a=explode("=",$current_url);
 echo $a[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode("=",$url) -- this will return you an array with the string split with "="

you can use $_GET['user']

Comment: thanks friends! `$_GET['user']` works perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string and then use explode to extract data after `=`.

For eg: Using url `http://www.site.com/index.php?user=username`

```
<?php

$text = explode("=", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
print_r($text);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "http://www.site.com/index.php?user"
    [1] => "username"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want the Value Passed through GET method
you can simply get its value like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['user']))
    $a=$_GET['user'];
?>
```

**Note:** Use this only if you are sure that after `?' and before`=` the variable is user else you can also use

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $a=explode("=",$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
    echo $a[1];}
else
    echo 'Please provide username';
?>
```

?>